# A way to background meterpreter sessions from an autorunscript

Tags: metasploit

I have been trying to figure out a way to script a way to background my auto run scripts. It seems like *everything* works perfectly fine with the exception of the *background* command.

For example:

```
kerberos credentials
====================

Username          Domain       Password
--------          ------       --------
(null)            (null)       (null)
metasploitable3$  contoso.com  8e 0f f5 ba aa b0 10 80 6b 26 eb 47 17 28 1e 5a 86 47 26 20 11 ba 27 34 fb 8c d5 2b 7f 46 b6 8f 9f 72 86 d1 16 3a c0 5c c1 fb a5 94 cc 86 21 ac 86 5b c2 21 0b 7c 5f 74 74 fe 05 4b 22 fa c5 a8 7d c7 93 1b be 90 dd 8f e3 36 58 41 c9 3c 77 30 d0 cb 10 67 e6 05 e0 f6 89 1a d7 b6 4e ac 29 01 79 1b 99 39 33 66 c2 75 0c a6 95 0d 33 a4 e2
 c6 27 a0 7f 4d a2 6c 9f 8d 22 4f ea fc f6 31 f1 ea 03 7e a0 67 03 1a 2a 25 ce be 7f a0 4f c0 59 ea 48 c5 b7 d1 c5 f6 be 98 32 1a 8a 17 80 73 20 f2 43 12 e9 20 9f f1 f1 44 bb bf 11 b5 37 69 25 46 cf ad ad c4 0a f0 82 f1 3a 96 84 f5 14 60 6d c6 da bf bd f4 0b f8 c7 c2 3d a6 01 50 e2 92 12 ac 3c 16 b2 0b a8 9e f5 98 d4 bb 69 5b 04 ef 32 85 ef cb 4d 51 71 87 6f ad
 b4 2a 9e 06 ed e8 65 da
metasploitable3$  CONTOSO.COM  bb 80 66 d8 22 87 98 ef 2e ba 8f b8 9b 8f 0c 8e 7f 8a 92 70 9d 02 da d7 25 41 ad 3e 33 f1 8c 5d 6e b2 8f 57 c1 81 e8 06 ac 07 b8 ac f2 f7 f0 54 86 bb 49 09 27 c7 c9 be 47 79 fe 51 b6 3f b0 2a 2d 2e 83 f9 4e 36 5c e3 4a 03 a3 8e 06 22 5c 98 52 d4 77 27 d0 d7 35 1a 79 7a bc 08 29 68 f4 c9 db fe 0a 5f 1f eb b2 e7 8d 4b 8b 3a 22
 0e f5 1f ec cf fb a5 af 4d b9 1c e5 72 a3 02 3a e4 ac e6 0d 98 4a d3 47 ad 69 22 7b 6c 56 29 34 8f 7f 85 0e 0c 8c 90 2f 82 d2 94 a5 1a f8 e2 18 e0 ab 23 5e 96 64 84 70 af b7 f2 c7 6b 41 11 2e fb 68 c5 de 76 06 2b 5d 5d c2 ab 07 47 65 2e ca 30 be 8b 04 c5 da 58 5f 8e 35 58 2e 2f 4a 26 f5 e6 d8 bb 9a 1c 16 34 8c 0e a4 7a 72 98 86 33 4a d1 26 60 00 1a b9 2f 76 98
 45 c1 e5 d4 94
sshd_server       contoso.com  [obfuscated]


[*]     Running command background
[*] Backgrounding session 3...
[*]     Running command background
[*] Backgrounding session 3...
[+] 172.28.128.5:445 - =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[+] 172.28.128.5:445 - =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-WIN-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[+] 172.28.128.5:445 - =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

meterpreter > help
```

As you can see above, the background command seems to be running, but it actually doesn't work in the meterpreter prompt. I have to manually type this in to get it to work. Any thoughts?